# Loading image from source folder returned as null

Tags: java, swing, file-io, null, embedded-resource

Hello I have a problem with importing an image from my resources folder. I have looked all over google (or so I think) and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

All help is appreciated thanks

Here is the picture of my java project:

[image: Here is my picture]

Here is my `Game` Code:

```
public Game(){

    handler = new Handler();
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));

    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Testing", this);

    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    level = loader.loadImage("/level.png");

    hud = new HUD();
    spawn = new Spawn(handler, hud);
    r = new Random();
    walls = new WallsMap(handler);
    cam = new Camera(0, 0);

    walls.render();  
    handler.addObject(new Player(WIDTH/2-32, HEIGHT/2-32, ID.Player, handler));
}
```

Finally here is my `BufferedImageLoader` class:

```
    public class BufferedImageLoader {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public BufferedImage loadImage(String path){
        try {
            image =  ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `"/res/level.png"`? Are you sure that the resource is been included within the resulting application Jar?

Comment: @MadProgrammer /res/level.png shouldn't work (and /level.png should...)

Comment: @immibis This assumes that `res` has been included within Eclipse's classpath/build path.  I don't know why people don't just dump into `src`...but I don't use Eclipse

Comment: @MadProgrammer the little package overlay on the folder icon tells you that it is a Java source folder.

Comment: @immibis Well, do you have any good ideas why it doesn't work then? Cause the code looks fine to me...

Comment: I know longer understand what is going on... Nothing is working, my game breaks in every way unless I remove the single line that loads the image. I've tried everything including absolute path so I have no idea what to do. It works in my other games/programs just not this one. Is there any other reason for input == null and NullPointerException?

Comment: Ok, well thanks for the help, I moved the `level = loader.loadImage("/level.png");` down so it was above `walls.render();` and now it works, I have no idea why but it works. It looks like it was a thread issue but I have no idea why. I suppose it was an order thing even though the BufferedImageLoader wasn't really dependent on anything else.

Comment: @Meeesh, that seems very unlikely. Move the line back up, and see what happens..

Answer (score 4):

To solve your particular problem, either of these two options should work so that the resource can be properly located:

- Remove the call to `getClassLoader()` from your loadImage method so that the call is just `getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)` -OR-
- Remove the slash from `"/level.png"` so that your call to loadImage looks like `loader.loadImage("level.png")`

However, in general, I agree with [mastercork889](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28491122/4376460), that it is better practice to organize your resources into packages as well.

EDIT:

In response to [mastercork889](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28491122/4376460)'s comment saying that my answer should be AND instead of OR, I thought I should elaborate on why it is indeed exclusive OR.  I would have just commented, but I'm still too new to stack overflow to be allowed to comment, and this is quite a bit of information anyway :)

Removing the call to `getClassLoader()` works because then you're using the `getResourceAsStream()` method from the `Class` class, which does extra work before delegation to the `getResourceAsStream()` method from the `ClassLoader` class.

From [the Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-):

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.

Since your resource isn't in a package, and is at the top level of a source folder (it looks like `res` is an "Eclipse Source Folder"), the `level.png` portion following the slash will adequately identify the location of the resource in an absolute way.

OR

Removing the slash from `"/level.png"` also works because then when the object's class loader (which should be the system class loader) looks for the resource, it will attempt to resolve your resource in an absolute way.  The special handling of the slash at the beginning is behavior that is specific to the `getResourceAsStream()` method in `Class`, not `ClassLoader`.

The reason that AND won't work, is because if you call the `getResourceAsStream()` method from `Class` and remove the slash, then it will attempt to locate the resource **in the same package** that the associated class is located in.  If you choose to go with the AND option, then you would need to move level.png into the `com.plat.gfx` package.

As a final point, I have built a small test program that followed the same format as your example, and once I followed one of the two suggestions, it worked for me.

The subtleties of resources, classes, and class loaders can be quite tricky.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: And you learn something new each day! Thanks for the clear up on that! I still think that the Questioner's fix is a bit... Off.. It just doesn't seem right. They must of altered their other code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about putting images in a specific folder. Instead put them also in the src folder under a specific package: `com.plat.res`

I find that putting images in a specific package makes the package hierarchy look much more efficient, and less spaghetti-like.

Also a note on package conventions: `domain-extension.domain.main-program.etc`. My package hierarchy looks like this:

```
com.brennytizer.jumg
com.brennytizer.jumg.res
com.brennytizer.jumg.engine
com.brennytizer.jumg.level
com.brennytizer.jumg.level.maps
```

If you don't have a domain, write in what you think your domain would be (if you were to buy it in the future), or just use your (backwards) name:

My name is `Jarod Brennfleck`, writing program `foobar`, my package would be: `brennfleck.jarod.foobar`.

Once in there use the [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class: `ImageIO.read(Game.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/plat/res/leve.png"));`

Comment: This is very weird, it still does not work, I am still unable to locate the file no matter where I put it. Also, when I comment out that single line everything works, once I use anything to try to load the image the game doesn't render anything and just crashes. Because of this I assume the code is still unable to locate the picture but it is there.

Comment: Ok update, after some testing I can confirm that the error occurs when I attempt to load the picture. Also, i tested everything using an absolute path, still an error, I am very confused right now.

Comment: Using your code, it WILL break. You must put your image in the SRC folder under a package. Then remove the `getClassLoader()`. thejonwithno has got it 50%. Instead of 'OR' it should be an AND, and put in the absolute path in the SRC folder. Exchange all decimals with a forward slash, except the file extension decimal. If this doesn't work. Repost your new code and screenshot of your package hierarchy.